# How to divide values using the total of a column

Tags: powerbi, dax

Below is a small snippet of my data. Now i want to create a new column `%ofSales` that takes the total of every `sub_group_name` and divides it with every value in the column of that sub group.

For example, the first value of the new column would be 
`(303370.88/186391.46)*100`

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets use this example data

```
category,subcategory,sales
1,       a,          2
1,       b,          4
1,       c,          5
1,       d,          6
2,       a,          3
2,       b,          4
2,       c,          2
2,       d,          5
```

Add calculated columns

```
catSales = 
var temp = Table2[category]
return CALCULATE(sum(Table2[sales]),all(Table2),Table2[category]=temp)

%ofSales = Table2[sales]/Table2[catSales]
```

Or use equivalent measures instead.

Result:

```
category,subcategory,sales,catSales,%ofSales
1,       a,          2,    17,      0.11764705882352941
1,       b,          4,    17,      0.23529411764705882
1,       c,          5,    17,      0.29411764705882354
1,       d,          6,    17,      0.35294117647058826
2,       a,          3,    14,      0.21428571428571427
2,       b,          4,    14,      0.2857142857142857
2,       c,          2,    14,      0.14285714285714285
2,       d,          5,    14,      0.35714285714285715
```

Edit: equivalent measure:

```
%ofSales2 = 
var temp = FIRSTNONBLANK(Table2[category],1)
return 
SUM(Table2[sales])/
CALCULATE(sum(Table2[sales]),
ALLSELECTED(Table2),
Table2[category]=temp)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but i am getting wrong totals. You can check in the image its showing the wrong total of the group. https://ibb.co/kuRPgQ

Comment: I get it. i have a date slicer. It gives me the correct values if i don't add the date slicer. But i can i do if i need the date slicer?

Comment: In that case use the measure